# Pass value back to global scope?

Tags: function, get, return

Just a simple one.

For example:

```
var myValue = 0;

function (){

var initialNumber = 4;
var numberToAdd = 2;

var finalNumber = numberToAdd+initialNumber;

}
```

How do I append the finalNumber and store inside the myValue variable?

Comment: uhhmmm what is that code suppose to do???

Comment: Also how do you think you can add the value to `myValue`?

Comment: The function is suppose to perform some calculation and store inside the global variable just like a calculator, I'm using action script previously and I can simply return the value I want using return but I'm not sure that is possible in javascript

Comment: How about... well.. idunno... this may sounds strange... try it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myValue = myFunction (2);

function myFunction (numberToAdd){
  var initialNumber = 4;
  return numberToAdd+initialNumber;
}
```